# How to create a dll-file from cs-files for nunit-console runner in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, nunit, nunit-console

I have many tests in the .cs format. When I want to run `nunit-console  C:\Users\...\Desktop\web-testing\xxxxxx.dll /output="C:\Users\...\Desktop\result.xml"`, I need a dll. But how to create this file?

Answer (score 0):

Using the exe-file

```
nunit-console  C:\Users\...\Desktop\web-testing\xxxxxx.exe /output="C:\Users\...\Desktop\result.xml"
```

is working.